# How to compare a metric from two custom time periods in one table in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have one data source connected to Looker Studio (for example GA/DV/ADS connector). I have data:

```
Date, Campaign, Clicks
2023-01-01, A, 100
2023-01-02, A, 2000
2023-01-01, B, 100
2023-01-02, C, 3000
2023-01-03, A, 1000
2023-01-04, A, 2500
2023-01-04, B, 1000
2023-01-05, C, 200
```

I want to show a % difference in my Clicks metric between two custom time periods in one table like this:

Looker Studio table:

```
Campaign, 01 to 03 Clicks (X), 04 to 06 Clicks (Y), Clicks % difference ((Y/X)-1)
A, 3100, 2500, -19%
B, 100, 1000, 900%
C, 3000, 200, -93%
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired results, you can follow these steps: Duplicate your data sources, then blend Data Source 1 with Date Range 1 and a copy of Data Source 1 with Date Range 2, and include Event Date, Campaign, and Click for both data sources.
Also, make sure to uncheck the "Hide repeated join fields" option.
After that, create a calculated metric and apply the desired function to it.